# On Reddit, how do scripts get the number of upvotes and downvotes for a comment?

Tags: javascript, api, greasemonkey, reddit

On [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/), people can post comments that get upvotes and downvotes. This information is not readily accessible on the page itself, so it seems that something like an API is used to gather this information.

I found [this script that does this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/56641), but am unable to determine where in the script it pulls this information from. Could someone point me to the relevant line where the script gets the data from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each comment has `data` attributes:

```
<div class="thing id-t1_c4upmtm odd comment " onclick="click_thing(this)" data-fullname="t1_c4upmtm" data-ups="646" data-downs="83">
```

Reddit's HTML structure is really hard to follow so figure out a way to get from the comment ID to the element which contains this stuff.

Comment: I pulled that HTML code directly from the source of the webpage. It corresponds to a comment.

Comment: Can you explain to me what a "thing" is?

Comment: Read [the API documentation](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/thing).  Although things can sometimes be "comments" per Reddit's classification, they are not what users would consider comments.  ... Things are usually top-level links.  Comments are usually made on/about things.  Note that it's been a while and I don't personally use Reddit, so some of this may be slightly off or outdated.   But, the *data-attribute* answer does not apply to what most people would consider comments on Reddit.

Comment: Actually to me, using Firebug, it looks like these data attributes also appear for comments as well as the submissions. I don't know why I missed this earlier, but thanks for pointing it out. Also, I gave the earlier solution an upvote too because I think that's still what the script does, which is odd if it can simply grab the data via HTML, but I imagine it merely does that because it grabs other data along with upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: Well you're right, the data is now there for comment and user pages.  (I could swear it was not there a week ago, but don't see a changelog for reddit.)  Obviously, this data was added sometime in the last few months -- after that script was written.

Comment: Those `data-` attributes apparently showed up two months ago: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/commit/9d69c78b36288ebd253db4a3d2b66edec8a73688

Comment: That's when the code was changed, not necessarily (or even probably) when the change went live on site

Answer (score 2):

That script uses `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` to fetch the JSON data for the given: comments or user page.

The data returned by `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`, is accessed in the line:

```
var jsonText = response.responseText,data;
```

and then parsed with the script's `processTree()` function.  There is not really one line; much of the script is required for this functionality.

On the comments pages, it seems that using the API is the only way to get up-votes and down-votes separately.