# grabbing Reddit data via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reddit

I came across this post, which is pretty much what I'm looking to do:

[How to extract url data from Reddit API using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191105/how-to-extract-url-data-from-reddit-api-using-json?rq=1)

I have modified the jsfiddle that was provided (**NSFW** http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/170/) to read:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", function(data) {
  $.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){
    console.log($('.score.likes').html(item));
  });
});
```

My goal is to gather the total amount of upvotes on a given page. When you run this and look at the console, objects are being returned but not the actual number. I thought just calling html on the selector would return the number of votes but apparently am wrong. Any better way of doing this?

Comment: When linking to adult content you should always inform people of this. I've edited your post to add **NSFW** (Not Safe For Work) before your JSFiddle link.

Comment: What's `$('.score.likes')` for - is that the page you're working on? You're not attempting to parse the JSON using CSS selectors?

Comment: Thanks James. I was just re-using the post and didn't think about it that way...thanks for clarifying. 

Rup - $('.score.likes') is the selector of the DOM element where the actual votes value is housed. I read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844664/on-reddit-how-do-scripts-get-the-number-of-upvotes-and-downvotes-for-a-comment that you can just grab it straight from the html...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `console.log(item)` to see the returned data. Using that we can then see that `item.data.score` returns the score of a post.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
        console.log(item.data);
        $('<div/>', {
            text: 'Post ' + item.data.permalink + ' has a score of ' + item.data.score
        }).appendTo('#images');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/353/

The reason you saw objects without number is because you called `console.log($('selector'))` and that returns the jQuery object not the json from the request.

Comment: ahhh perfect! thank you Spokey. exactly what I was looking for! still have 9 minutes on the accept...